# How to enable Bank transfer in Stripe inside the list of already available payment methods?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the Bank transfer to show up in the list of payment methods, so when I do this:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount,
  currency: currency as string,
  metadata,
  description,
  payment_method_data: {
    type: 'customer_balance',
  },
  customer: customer.id,
  payment_method_options: {
    customer_balance: {
      bank_transfer: {
        type: 'eu_bank_transfer',
        eu_bank_transfer: { country },
      },
      funding_type: 'bank_transfer',
    },
  },
  payment_method_types: ['customer_balance'],
})
```

It does work and I can see it, I can also add `card` in the `payment_method_types` array and it will show both, however the shop supports over 20 countries and we have many other payment methods available. Up until now the way it worked was:

```
stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount,
  currency: currency as string,
  metadata,
  description,
  automatic_payment_methods: { enabled: true },
  customer: customer.id
})
```

And it worked just fine, all payment methods showed up just fine, the question is how to combine them with the Bank payment method? When I try to combine the two objects, I get an error saying:

`You may only specify one of these parameters: ["automatic_payment_methods", "payment_method_types"].`

Does that mean that for the simple change of wanting to have `Bank` show up in the already existing list, I have to hardcode myself all of the settings for all of the different payment methods and create appropriate payment intents based on the country (something that Stripe already does when its automatic)?

Comment: When you use `automatic_payment_methods.enabled: true`, doesn't the bank payment method show? Why do you need manually defining `payment_method_types`?